# How can I get particular product if in all category?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tables as below

### CATEGORY TABLE

```
╔════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║
╠════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ cat 1 ║
║  2 ║ cat 2 ║
║  3 ║ cat 3 ║
╚════╩═══════╝
```

### PRODUCT table

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ CATEGORYID ║ PRODUCTNAME ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║          1 ║ product1    ║
║  2 ║          1 ║ product2    ║
║  3 ║          1 ║ product3    ║
║  4 ║          2 ║ product1    ║
║  5 ║          2 ║ product2    ║
║  6 ║          3 ║ product1    ║
║  7 ║          3 ║ product3    ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

### OUTPUT table

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ CATEGORYID ║ PRODUCTNAME ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║          1 ║ product1    ║
║  4 ║          2 ║ product1    ║
║  6 ║          3 ║ product1    ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

As in each category there is a product name "product1" so I need a list of products that are available in all the category.

Can any one help me how to do it with SQL Server T-SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Product a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ProductName
            FROM    Product
            GROUP   BY ProductName
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category)
        ) b ON a.ProductName = b.ProductName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65e78/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ CATEGORYID ║ PRODUCTNAME ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║          1 ║ product1    ║
║  4 ║          2 ║ product1    ║
║  6 ║          3 ║ product1    ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select p.*, count(*) over (partition by PRODUCTNAME) cats
 from product p)
select ID, CATEGORYID, PRODUCTNAME
from cte p
join (select count(*) totcats from category) c
on p.cats=c.totcats
```

Comment: This should run on sqlserver 2005, 2008 and 2012 - for example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65e78/11

Comment: yes' you;re right. I made a typo before that's why I told you about this. sorry. deleting my old comment.

Answer (score 0):

Option with [NOT EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) and [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operators

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT p3.[ID]
                  FROM dbo.Category p3                  
                  EXCEPT
                  SELECT p2.[CAtegoryID]
                  FROM dbo.Product p2
                  WHERE p2.[productName] = p.[productName]                        
                  )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06f6a/1)

For improving performance use this index

```
CREATE INDEX ix_ID_Category ON Category(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Via EXISTS

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Product a
where exists
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Product
            where a.ProductName = Product.ProductName
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category)
        )
```